# Chrome Packaged Application Can't Open Same-Window Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am developing simple Chrome packaged app. I am newbie on chrome app development.I am getting an error when I run applicaiton.

The error message is : **Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://ckikacajammagdadocdkmcoecilafkgl/index.html"; try target="_blank".**

Index HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first Chrome App</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnTest" value="Test" style="width: 200px; height: 40px">TEST</button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="txtTest" />
    <div id="divMovies" style="width: 100%;">
        <br />
        Url : 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    save(load);
});

function save(callback) {
    var channel = "Test local storage item test";
    chrome.storage.local.set({ 'channel': channel });
    callback();
}
function load() {
    var channelss = "";
    chrome.storage.local.get('channel', function (result) {
        channelss = result;
    });
    document.getElementById("txtTest").value = channelss.channel;
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Dizi Takip App",  
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "128": "icon.png" },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

main.js :

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {width: 500, height: 309});
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The only thing we can tell that you did wrong is that you failed to include the code that is causing the error. Does the console error message contain a file and line number? What is the contents of index.html? What is the contents of manifest.json? Which file is referring to this "custom js file"? Etc.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer. I edited my question and added all of my simple app's files. So what is wrong?

Comment: It gives an error on customjs file document.getElementById("txtTest").value = channelss.channel line

Comment: One possible problem is that the line giving the error is going to execute before the line that assigns "result" to "channelss". (At least, sometimes it will; you can't tell for sure because it's asynchronous.) Did you intend that? Why did you separate the assignment of "result" and the usage of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.storage.*.set` and `chrome.storage.*.get` are both asynchronous APIs (as sowbug has noted). So you need to change your custom.js to look like this:

```
function save(callback) {
    var channel = "Test local storage item test";
    chrome.storage.local.set({ 'channel': channel }, function() {
        callback();
    });
}

function load() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('channel', function (result) {
        document.getElementById("txtTest").value = result.channel;
    });
}
```

However, the error that you're mentioning doesn't make any sense for this app, and is definitely not related to the problem in custom.js. You would normally see this error if your app had in its HTML code a link without the target='_blank' attribute, and the user clicked on that link. Apps don't have a built-in concept of in-window navigation, so such links are prohibited. You can either specify target='_blank' for the link and have it open a new tab/window in the user's default browser (not necessarily Chrome!), or add an onclick handler to the link and do something fancier in there.

I recreated your app given your sources, and it worked out of the box, with the exception that txtTest said "undefined" in the absence of the above changes. But no error (any error) was reported anywhere. I didn't, however, use jQuery. Instead, I used the following in custom.js to initiate the sequence:

```
onload = function () {
    save(load);
};
```

If you can verify that you're getting the error with $(document).ready and not getting it with onload, please let us know.

Comment: I changed custom.js with your code, I didnt change $(document).ready block. You are the life-time saver. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

chrome.app.window.create requires "app.window" permission in the manifest

Comment: In a way, you are right: chrome.app.window.* APIs do require "app.window" permission. However, that permission is currently implied for all Chrome packaged apps, that is, it gets implicitly injected for all apps, and you don't have to explicitly specify it in the manifest (although you can, and that won't create an error). The public documentation at http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html is a little behind about this, but that's going to be fixed very soon.